# Entity Remove() is setting foreign key properties to null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-4

I have a One-to-Many relationship as shown below - the child in the relationship is soft-deleted and the string foreign key is non-nullable/`[Required]` however I'm having issues when I try to remove the child as EF is setting the foreign key id to null so when I `SaveChangesAsync` its throwing `DbEntityValidationException`  because of the `[Required]` attribute as the Id is null thus invalidating the `[Required]` rule

I understand this is default behavior of EF to set the Id's to null but was wondering if there's a workaround in this scenario? One solution I had was to set the Id's again after `Remove()` which works fine but feels like a bit of a hack and unsure if this will have further implications

User:

```
[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Item:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User { get; set; }

public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

Removing the item:

```
var item = db.Items.Where(x => x.Id == ItemId).FirstOrDefault(); //item.UserId is not null here
db.Items.Remove(item); //item.UserId is now null after Remove
db.SaveChanges()
```

Current workaround:

```
db.Items.Remove(item); //item.UserId is now null after Remove
item.UserId = originalUserId //item.UserId is no longer null and will validate successfully
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove required, the only way is  to assign the new user at first. It doesn't make any sense to keep required and not assign a new user

```
item.UserId=newUserId
```

after this you can remove previous User without any problem.

As a work around you can create a fake user with name "Deleted", and use it temporarily, but I really can' t see why do you need it. Why just dont remove requiered attribute?

Comment: Because I'd like the string foreign key to not be nullable - if I remove the `[Required]` then it will save the soft-deleted `Item` with a null `UserId`. By soft deleting its a kind of way to keep a historical so we'd like to keep the UserId intact. As I mentioned this work around does work where you re-assign the original UserId but was just wondering if there was a better way to do this that is less-hacky

Comment: Also I'm just trying to remove `Item` not user.

Comment: @jspk501 You have to show the real code then. The way it is now, you can remove item without any problem. If you have problem it means that you have  an itemId somewhere else, UserId has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `UserId` is being set null by `Remove()` is the problem. When `SaveChanges()` happens after removing the `Item` it throws `DbEntityValidationException` because the `Item.UserId` is null and has a `[Required]` on it